# Problem Adding Custom Structural Block

Tags: blocks, ce-1.9.0.1, local.xml

I am attempting to add a slide-out menu to my Magento site, and I would like to inject the HTML by using the `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>` method. This menu would be universal to the entire desktop version of my website, so I want it to appear on all of the page templates (1column, 2column-right, 2-column-left, etc). I got the menu working perfectly on all templates by copy/pasting it into all of the aforementioned page templates, but this strikes me as bad coding practice—every time I edit the menu, I don't want to have to make the same change in 4 other files. That's why I want to use the `getChildHtml()` method; I would edit my `menu.phtml` and all layouts would be affected uniformly.

I followed the simple tutorial [here](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-reference-structural-block/) but my `getChildHtml('menu')` is returning empty. I'll post my relevant code below. If someone could spot where I messed up—or failing that, suggest a different way to inject HTML dynamically (similar to JSP's `<jsp:include page="..." />` method, maybe?)—I would really appreciate it. FYI I am using Magento CE 1.9.0.1.

Code:

template/theme = warrior/default

in `app\design\frontend\warrior\default\layout\local.xml`, I have:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="menu" as="menu" translate="label">
                <label>Slide Menu</label>
            </block>
        </reference>

        <reference name="menu">
            <block type="core/template" name="menu" template="menu.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

in `app\design\frontend\warrior\default\template\page\1column.phtml`, I have (excerpt):

```
    <div class="main-container col1-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

                <!-- My code -->
                <div> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('menu') ?> </div> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

in `app\design\frontend\warrior\default\template\menu.phtml`, I have:
    `<h1 style="background-color:yellow;"> sup dawg </h1>`

And the resultant HTML in my browser is this: `<div>   </div>` in the correct place, after the `content` block (I only have it in that specific spot to test this method. The actual menu code will go before the header).

Thanks in advance,
Ezra ♡

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the code as:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="menu" as="menu" template="menu.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

You don't need the second reference.

Comment: I think it's `type="core/template"`, and a label isn't needed too ? Also an explanation of why the nesting is needed would be great

Comment: MTM, do you mean that I should use this code in my local.xml instead of what I have? Or in addition to? Or inside the `<layout> <default> ... </default> </layout>` block of code? I am new to Magento and I would really appreciate a little more specificity :)

Comment: Okay, after trying it a few different ways, I got it to work with your code, wrapped by `<layout> <default> ... </default> </layout>`. Thanks! EDIT: only works using the `type` @Niloct provided.

Comment: @Niloct, i didn't tested the code, just wanted to tell to use template in root, don't need the second one. and yes the block type is to be core/template. will update the post